# Adding role based user Authorization layer to my Angular-fullstack website

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authorization, crud, angular-fullstack

I have started a MEAN application and used a yeoman generator - [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) and then used a [angular fullstack crud generator](https://github.com/MartyIce/generator-angular-fullstack-crud) so I have a basic template ready and now I want to add custom authorization middleware to it so that I can assign different permissions for all operations to individual models/entities both on client(angular ui router way) and server. So, how do i start off, is there any module that achieves the same end result automatically or if anyone can give me a nice reference point to begin with i would solve this problem on my own.

Thank You